# Where are the comments stored?

Tags: 7, rating

I need to know where the mandatory comment that we have set up in the Voting API module is stored. I can find the scores in the voting_api table, but not those comments.

I need to do a query in a module to get this information. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps in the variables table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they were stored in the content of a specific node type, with custom code.